# PHP error handling with .htaccess & writing into php_error.log text file

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, text-files, error-logging

For PHP error handling with the aim of "only admin sees the warnings, errors etc.";

I applied the steps below:

1. I deleted `error_reporting(-1);` command from my `index.php`
2. I added rows below into my `.htaccess` which is just under `public_html` folder
3. I created `error_modes` folder in my `public_html` folder
4. I created `.htaccess` file in `error_modes` folder
5. I set the permissions of the `error_modes` folder as `777`, writable.
6. intentionally, I wrote `<?php 'should see this error in log file' ?>` in my `footer.inc.php` page. Please note that I didn't wrote `;` character at the end.

**Despite** the intentional **php syntax error** in my `footer.inc.php` page, **no `php_error.log` file is created!**

**and I saw that *should see this error in log file* `string` is printed in my `footer.inc.php` page. So php worked despite a syntax error !?**

I also added my whole `.htaccess` code below. (this is the one that is just under `public_html`)

**fyi**: I don't have access to `php.ini` and I don't have any pre-set `.log` file. PHP version is 5.4.

Can you please correct me? Thanks. Best Regards.

### added commands into public_html > .htaccess for error handling

```
php_flag  log_errors on
php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_log  /home/my_user_number/public_html/error_modes/php_error.log
php_value error_reporting -1
```

### codes in error_modes > .htaccess

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
```

### whole codes in public_html > .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#always use www - redirect non-www to www permanently
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# hotlink protection
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.p.ht [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js)$ - [NC,F,L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# File caching is another famous approach in optimizing website loading time
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf|js|css|pdf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

# disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# secure htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# secure password file
<Files .mypassword>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# secure spesific files
<Files secret.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

# secure spesific files
<Files secret2.php>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>

#SEO friendly linking
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?page=articles&subject=$1&object=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ index.php?page=articles&subject=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^labels/(.+)$ index.php?page=labels&subject=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]

#error handling
php_flag  log_errors on
php_flag display_errors off
php_value error_log  /home/my_user_number/public_html/error_modes/php_error.log
php_value error_reporting -1
```

Comment: might be your file error.log is Readonly ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try to do the following:

### In .htaccess

```
    # supress php errors
    php_flag display_startup_errors off
    php_flag display_errors off
    php_value docref_root 0
    php_value docref_ext 0


    # enable PHP error logging
    php_flag  log_errors on
    php_value error_log  /correct_path_to_your_website/error_modes/PHP_errors.log


    # general directive for setting php error level
    php_value error_reporting -1
```

### In php file

Instead of intentional mistake in you wrote in your php file you can try doing something like:

```
    <?

    echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // this will enable you to see 
                                    // the correct path to your website dir 
                                    // which should be written in .htaccess 
                                    // instead of correct_path_to_your_website
                                    // (check it just in case)

    $foo = $bar['nope'];// this should generate notice 

    call_undefined(); // this should generate fatal error


    ?>
```

Worked good with me)

Hope it'll help.

Comment: thanks. I've tried. nothing changed. my full path has been printed as string. no `log` file has been cretaed :-(

Comment: /home/usernumber/public_html

Comment: Yes, this is correct.
And also, just in case, the code for .htaccess above is for your public_html/.htaccess not for .htaccess file in error_modes folder.

Comment: And also) The path to the error log in web is case-sensitive. So make sure you check exactly http://your_site/error_modes/PHP_errors.log

Comment: it worked, actually I renewed connection in filezilla so I saw my error log file. thanks, BR